# Get numbers, booleans and strings from string

Tags: c#

I have string type,name 2 doubles and 1 boolean in my string. Please help me with parsing it.

```
string type,name; 
bool isChocolate;
double weight, price;
string line = "Candy Red Riding Hood,0.17,2.21,true"; 
if (line.ToLower().Contains("candy"))
{
    type = "candy";
    line = line.ToLower().Replace("candy", " ").Trim();
    if (line.ToLower().Contains("true"))
    {
        isChocolate = true;
        line = line.ToLower().Replace("true", " ").Trim();
    }
    else if(line.ToLower().Contains("false"))
    {
        line = line.ToLower().Replace("false", " ").Trim();
    }
 }
```

Then I get stuck. For me it doesn't matter which of 2 doubles will be a price and which - for weight.

Comment: Can you use String splitting to create an array and the just do some try casts?

Comment: I would start by doing this `var list = line.Split(',');` then you can loop over the contents of that and do some try parses perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string.Split`.

```
string line = "Candy Red Riding Hood,0.17,2.21,true";

var parts = line.Split(',');

string stringValue = parts[0];
double weight = double.Parse(parts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double price = double.Parse(parts[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
bool boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(parts[3]);
```

Comment: This answers exactly what the OP wanted to know, short and sweet.

Comment: Jim, that removed his comment for 'For me it doesn't matter which of 2 doubles' is a genius! If the customer puts weight instead of price and vice versa why should it bother me!

Comment: So split is the best decision after checking that string is for candy. Great thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know the pattern for your line, then you can define a regexp and the groups within.

https://regex101.com/r/kLphgk/1

And the code would look like this

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"^(?<type>\w+)\s*(?<name>[^,]+),(?<weight>\d+(.\d+)?),(?<price>\d+(.\d+)?),(?<state>(true|false))$");
var match = rgx.Match("Candy Red Riding Hood,0.17,2.21,true");
var obj = new {
    Type = match.Groups["type"].Value,
    Name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
    Price = double.Parse(match.Groups["price"].Value),
    Weight = double.Parse(match.Groups["weight"].Value),
    State = bool.Parse(match.Groups["state"].Value)
};
```

Comment: @Downvoter OK I wouldn't use this long regex too, but what is the reason to download a working code? .... Just because you can't understand it?